# Android SoftKeyboard shortcut

Tags: android, keyboard, shortcut

I have a question. I wanted to develop an app that would add a shortcut to the keyboard (Samsung SoftKeyboard).
The shortcut should be accessible via the dots at the top right (see attachment).

I would like to add a circle ("floating") over my app, as shown in the picture on the right.
Something specific should then be carried out via this circle (but that's not the point yet).

I've done a little research, but don't really know what to look for.

I hope you can help me.
thanks in advance

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl8Ae.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no such possibility to add anything in there. it's another app with own custom settings and options, you can't edit such or change in any way. your last chance is possibility of published API/some communication way for that app, which would allow to add such actions, but I very doubt Samsung made such API for own keyboard app and allowed ANY 3rd-party app to mess in their software... (btw. that would be very insecure for user)